# HTML 5 video element shows blank in a iframe opened in a bootstrap for an iPhone

Tags: ios, html, iframe, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I have a sharepoint page having a boostrap modal. An iframe is set in the modal. In the page loaded to this iframe, I have a HTML 5 video element, whose source is set dynamically. This works fine in all browsers but not in iPhone. The whole modal shows a blank space. However, on tapping the blank space, the video plays.

Please help to fix this.

Comment: This issue doesnt occur for audio element.

Comment: can you post the code you have?

Comment: are you getting any console output?  Errors?